# gmapping output very large 4000X4000?

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

We just ran Pioneer with ROS navigation stack with slam_gmapping node.
The output of the map is 4000x4000 (appx. 15 MB) irrespective of size of environment explored.

If I try to use this map for sbpl_lattice_planner, it just waits for the map. I can visualize map in rviz. The map is grey (may be to refer to unknown area). But rviz & system hangs.

Is this behaviour because of big size of map??
I can not find which parameters to use to set map bounds? Any  ideas?

Update 1: I tested it one other laptop. I may be because of hardware problem , not able to handle Rviz! is it possible with i5 processor?
prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30038/gmapping-output-very-large-4000x4000?/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [parameter section of the gmapping documentation](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping#Parameters).
You can set the parameters xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax to some small values (like 5 meters or so). You can also adjust the resolution by setting delta.

[Here is an example for an launch file with the values set.](http://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/%7Eaba879/ros/slam_gmapping_haw.launch) (10m x 10m map, 2cm resolution)

Regards Ben

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-20**:
Thanks ben, i got about size.

**Comment by [cooper](https://answers.ros.org/users/40631/cooper/) on 2019-05-30**:
hey example link is not working....